# Link to dynamic active class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, flux

router for routing purpose in my react app.

Mine routing is defined in given manner:

```
<Route path={food/:cuisine/:pageNo} component={foodList}
```

and my navBar have following navigation:

```
<Link to={"/food/italian/1"} activeClassName="active">Italian</Link>
<Link to={"/food/indian/1"} activeClassName="active">Indian</Link>
```

but when visit page no. 2("/food/indian/2") of that component then myActive class of navBar is not showing.
If there are any alternate method to solve this problem then it will be great.

Thanks.

---

PS: I don't want to put all conditions like because the app has more than 15 different cuisine

```
if(this.props.params.cuisine=="Indian){
    //then add .active in my Link to class
}
```

=======

Comment: try to ClassName instead of activeClassName.

Comment: @Jean-maxime Bouloc if u know the answer then u can edit this question. Putting one space or removing one extra is not going to solve this question. If u want to get too much reputation then start aswering questions instead of putting one extra space in if consition.

Comment: Have you tried using `activeStyle`? [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/05-active-links#active-styles)

Comment: @AmitJamwal , I already mention that I don't want to use that variable method inside className. There will be 15 different cuisine and I have to write 15 different variable className and give conditions on the basis of this.props.params.cuisine

Comment: I think issue with routes. Can i see your route configuration?

Comment: @HardikModha, Yes I tried that one, Its the same as activeClass only inline styling of that HTML. If I will go to next page i.e. page no. 2 then activeStyle will not work

Comment: Are you using IndexLink. If not than try to use IndexLink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use conditional javascript for given case.

like :

```
    if(this.props.params.cuisine=="Indian){
    //then add .active in my Link to class
}
```

it will work perfectly for you. `activeClass` will compare whole route path and if it's true then they will add class active.

**Alternate option**: If u can create a constant value using `splice` function of javascript to get ur suffix of url .

then create two variable.

for example:

```
var indianPrefix= "/food/indian/"+ urlSuffix;
var italianPrefix= "/food/italian/"+ urlSuffix;
```

then use:

```
<Link to={italianPrefix} activeClassName="active">Italian</Link>
<Link to={indianPrefix} activeClassName="active">Indian</Link>
```

**bug**: By using this method on clicking the tab you will be landing on the same page always.

Thanks.